# How do I get rid of showing all buttons during preload of a web app?

Tags: firebase

When I load my web app, for 1-2 seconds both the sign in and sign out button show before only one of the buttons stays. How do I get rid of that 1-2 seconds where both buttons are showing and have only one of the buttons show initially?

Index.html:

```
<div id="signin" class="Signin-div">
  <button onclick="login()">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div id="signout" class="signout-div">
  <button id="signout" onclick="signOut()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

Js File

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("User Signed in");
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "initial";
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log("User Signed out");
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="signin" class="Signin-div" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="login()">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div id="signout" class="signout-div" style="display: none;">
  <button id="signout" onclick="signOut()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log("User Signed in");
    document.getElementById("signout").style.display = "initial";
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log("User Signed out");
    document.getElementById("signin").style.display = "initial";
  }
});
```